# An error occured while executing doInBackground(). FATAL EXCEPTION:AsyncTask #10

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-async-http

On the click event add data to `MySQL` database through `php` on the localhost. Its showing following logcat error on the click event. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
08-11 07:31:06.416: D/gralloc_goldfish(971): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-11 07:31:53.377: D/Inside Click(971): aaaaaaa
08-11 07:31:53.837: D/inid doinbackground(971): aaaaaaa
08-11 07:31:53.927: W/dalvikvm(971): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
08-11 07:31:54.047: E/AndroidRuntime(971): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-11 07:31:54.047: E/AndroidRuntime(971): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-11 07:31:54.047: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
08-11 07:31:54.047: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-11 07:31:54.047: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-11 07:31:54.047: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
08-11 07:31:54.047: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-11 07:31:54.047: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-11 07:31:54.047: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-11 07:31:54.047: E/AndroidRuntime(971): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 07:31:54.047: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at com.example.connectiondemo.MainActivity$CreateBooking.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
08-11 07:31:54.047: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-11 07:31:54.047: E/AndroidRuntime(971):  ... 5 more
08-11 07:31:58.986: I/Process(971): Sending signal. PID: 971 SIG: 9
```

My Activity

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;

import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String url="http://10.0.2.2/styletapphp/create_booking.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS="Success";
    JSONParser jsonParser;
    JSONObject json;

    TextView t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        t2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);
        t3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t3);
        t4=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t4);
        t5=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t5);
        t6=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t6);
        t7=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t7);
        t8=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t8);
        //t9=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t8);
        t1.setText("Date");
        t2.setText("Stylist");
        t3.setText("9to10");
        t4.setText("10to11");
        t5.setText("11to12");
        t6.setText("12to1");
        t7.setText("2to3");
        t8.setText("3to4");

        Button butt1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        butt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Inside Click","aaaaaaa");
                //new CreateBooking().execute();
                new CreateBooking().execute("Date","Stylist", "9to10", "10to11", "11to12", "12to1","2to3", "3to4"); 
            }
        });
    }
 class CreateBooking extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

             Log.d("inid doinbackground","aaaaaaa");
             List<NameValuePair> namevaluepair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bookingdate", params[0]));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stylist", params[1]));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status9to10", params[2]));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status10to11", params[3]));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status11to12", params[4]));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status12to1", params[5]));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status2to3", params[6]));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status3to4", params[7]));
                /*List<NameValuePair>namevaluepair=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bookingdate",t1.getText().toString()));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stylist",t2.getText().toString()));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status9to10",t3.getText().toString()));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status10to11",t4.getText().toString()));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status11to12",t5.getText().toString()));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status12to1",t6.getText().toString()));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status2to3",t7.getText().toString()));
                namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status3to4",t8.getText().toString()));*/

                 json=jsonParser.makehttpRequest(url,"POST",namevaluepair);

                        Log.d("Create booking response",json.toString());

                // check for success tag
                try{int success=json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                publishProgress(success);

                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return null;
        }
        /*protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
            super.onPostExecute(integer);
            if (integer == null)
                return;
            if (integer.intValue() == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "booking successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "booking not successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(int i)
        {
           super.onPostExecute(i);

            if (i==1){
                // successfully created product
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "booking successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                 // failed to create product
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "booking not successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }




           // if condition and toast message

        } */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            if (values[0] == null)
                return;
            if (values[0].intValue() == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "booking successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "booking not successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: @user:According to log.I just found that you need to create a new emulator virtual device and set GPU emulation to true in Hardware properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonParser` has never been initialized. You need to initialize before you can use it.

Also you can not make Network requests on the `UIThread`. This will cause a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. You will need to use an `AsyncTask`. Check this [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)